# Downloading website with wget or httrack yields error "301 Moved Permanently"

Tags: download, wget, download-manager, httrack

I am trying to download https://untools.co/ with wget or httrack, but I repeatedly get the error "301 Moved Permanently". I get the main page downloaded, but once I open the index.html with a browser and try to click on some of the links I get redirected to a non-existing file.

I have tried commands like

```
wget --mirror --domains=untools.co untools.co
wget -np -r -k --convert-links "https://www.untools.co/"
httrack "https://untools.co/" -O "./untools" "+*.untools.co/*" --ext-depth 3
```

and tried to read a lot of documentation, but must admit I am somewhat lost, being completely new to those tools.

(I am on Linux Kubuntu - not sure if that is relevant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run following command

```
wget --mirror --convert-links https://www.untools.co/
```

then opened `index.html` using Firefox and was able to access tools (I checked 3: *Eisenhower Matrix, Ishikawa Diagram, Minto Pyramid*) without issues. Be warned that [wget convert links after all download are done](https://danielmalmer.medium.com/heres-why-wget-s-convert-links-option-isn-t-converting-your-links-cec832ee934c) therefore you must not open any file before `wget` finish running.

Comment: When I open `index.html` firefox "writes" `file:///` into the address bar and then I get a view of all my files on my computer. I am on Linux Kubuntu - not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: @Make42 `file` denotes that you are viewing local file

Comment: I mean, when I open the file `index.html` with firefox, the address in the address bar of Firefox is substituted, so that literally `file:///` is left. In other words, Firefox opens up the root folder of my Linux directory tree, instead of the `index.html` file. For half a second the html is displayed, but then the redirection takes place.  See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrn4K.png

Comment: @Make42 what happens if you will use other browser?

Comment: exactly the same

Comment: @Make42 I do not know how to solve that, as I have not experience with *Kubuntu*, one action I might suggest is opening index.html using text editor and to check if links (href attributes values) were converted, when compared to these seen by inspecting page online. If yes `wget` worked correctly and now you need to find some kubuntu ninja to solve problem with *firefox* rather than `wget`.

Comment: It seems you are right: I opened the `index.html` in a virtual machine Windows with Firefox and the file was properly displayed. Since the issue is with all browsers in Linux, it must be something with the OS, not with a particular browser. I have no idea what the issue could be - not even how to phrase a question though.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708325/122989 explains that "the main index.html contains some embedded Javascript that forces a redirect to /." A solution is "to run a local webserver." The post explains the details.